# Вывод данных в QTextEdit в виде столбцов

Tags: c++, qt

При работе в qt с QTextEdit столкнулась с проблемой вывода данных в ровные столбцы. Непонятно, как делать форматирование строк.

Пока код в таком виде:

```
while (query.next())
      {
      QString id = query.value(0).toString();
      QString surname = query.value(1).toString();
      QString name = query.value(2).toString();
      QString name2 = query.value(3).toString();
      QString id_costume = query.value(4).toString();
      QString size = query.value(5).toString();

ui->textEdit->insertPlainText(id+ " " +surname+" "+name+" "+name2+" "+id_costume+ " "+size+"\n");
      }
```

Выводит в следующем виде:

```
№ Фамилия:  Имя:    Отчество:    костюм: размер: 
1 Петров Иван Иванович 123 1
4 Иванов Петр Васильевич 1234 2
```

А желательно в следующем:

```
 № Фамилия:  Имя:    Отчество:    костюм: размер: 
 1 Петров    Иван    Иванович     123     1
 4 Иванов    Петр    Васильевич   1234    2
```

Comment: Приведите в вопросе как должно было вывести. Кст, а почему бы через QTableWidget? Или уж QTableView + QSqlQueryModel?

Comment: я думаю, Вам должно помочь использование символа табуляции `\t` в качестве разделителя. Но при возможности все таки стоит рассмотреть использование `QTableWidget` (это избавит вас от лишних методов составления корректно отображающихся в `QTextEdit` строк и разбора данных в случае их редактирования).

Comment: Попробуйте, как предложил Bogdan, `\t`, а я бы дополнил еще одним советом. Шрифты бывают пропорциональные и моноширинные. Моноширинный шрифт означает что каждый символ имеют одинаковую ширину. Для вашей задачи нужно будет у QTextEdit указать такой шрифт, по этой теме: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%88%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%82

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения подобной задачи можно использовать символ табуляции `\t`, но его использование порождает много проблем.

Примерами таких проблем могут быть:

- составление корректного формата строк для отображения (надо вывести все красиво);
- разбор этого формата (если данные были отредактированы);
- колдовство с ошибками в этом формате (если при редактировании пользователь случайно удалил "специальные символы" на которые ориентируется метод разбора данных).

Проблемы с отображением при значениях столбцов разной длины тоже не будут неожиданностью (таб во второй строке не влезает, соответственно вся строка сдвигается):

```
№  Имя     Фамилия      Возраст
1  Ян      Петров       21
2  Александр      Васильев      24
3  Виктор  Иванов       22
```

В `QTextEdit` есть возможность вставлять HTML (например при помощи метода [insertHtml](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qtextcursor.html#insertHtml)), так что, можно копнуть и в эту сторону (вставить HTML-таблицу). Но, имхо, это больше похоже на шаманство.

**Итог**: использование `QTextEdit` для табличного отображения данных чревато множеством подводных камней и граблей, поэтому есть смысл рассмотреть более подходящие варианты (в простейшем случае это может быть [QTableWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html)).